# How to get promise value correctly?

Tags: promise

Consider the following code:

```
function toolsQueryResult(){
    const query = `query{......}`  
    return request('http://...', query,).then(data =>  { return data })
}   

   var toolsQueryResult= toolsQueryResult();
   var toolsNames      = [];


   toolsQueryResult.then(function(result){
   result['key'].forEach(function(item){
    toolsNames.push(item["name"])
  })
 })

console.log(toolsNames)
```

This returns and prints out empty list "[ ]" to me.Does any one know why?
But if I put "console.log()" between two final "})", it returns list of tools correctly.How should I work with this promise object to have list of tools correctly after second "})" at the end of code?

Comment: `toolsQueryResult= toolsQueryResult()`. Don't ever do that.

Comment: "*How should I work with this promise object to have list of tools correctly after second "})" at the end of code?*"- that's not possibly. By the time that statement runs, the request has not yet finished. Just put the log where it works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, your `console.log` statement is executed before the the promise `toolsQueryResult` is resolved. It would be really useful and helpful if you have debugger tools on and place breakpoints to see what i just said.

That said,having the `console.log` outside of the promise being resolved or rejected beats the whole purpose, meaning you are trying to output a statement before it could complete its execution, hence when you place the `console.log` statement inside of the `then` function it outputs result.

Fiddle with your code (modified the result to be a simple array) for you to debug and see : https://jsfiddle.net/jayas_godblessall/vz8mcteh/

or execute it here to see :

```js
function toolsQueryResult() {
  const query = `query{......}`
  return request('http://...', query, ).then(data => {
    return data
  })
}

// just to emulate your api call
function request(foo) {
  return Promise.resolve(["item1", "item2"]);
}

var toolsQueryResult = toolsQueryResult();
var toolsNames = [];


toolsQueryResult.then(function(result) {
  result.forEach(function(item) {
    toolsNames.push(item)
  })
  console.log("am executed after you waited for promise to complete - in this case successfully, so you can see the tool sets")
  console.log(toolsNames)

  
})

console.log("am executed before you could resolve promise")
console.log(toolsNames)
```